# Put three js body as partial view (via iframe) in asp net mvc

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, three.js

I use asp net mvc. I have a view in which I invoke (via ajax) the controller method that returns partial view with three js render. This partial view put in view (iframe tag) (as well as in examples on official site of three js). But in success event of ajax I have null data. Help solve this problem please. 
This part of the main page:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 pt-3" style="height:100%;">
                    <iframe id="viewer" name="viewer" >
                    </iframe>
            </div>
```

This code of the partial view:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/visualize/three.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="../../Scripts/visualize/Detector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            var WIDTH = 320,
            HEIGHT = 200;

            var renderer, scene, camera, cube;

            function onLoad() {
                var container = document.getElementById("container");

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 1000);
                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                scene.add(camera);
                camera.position.z = 300;

                cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200));
                cube.position.y = 0;
                cube.position.z = -150;
                scene.add(cube);

                requestAnimationFrame(render);
            };

            function render() {
                requestAnimationFrame(render);

                cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };
        </script>
    </head>

<body onload="onLoad();">
    <div id="container" style="border:1px solid black;width:320px;height:240px;"></div>
</body>
```

this code that calling control method and put the partial view in div with id=viewer:

```
$("#btncalc").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("PartialPack", "Home")',
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#viewer').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            });
```

this code of controller method:

```
public PartialViewResult PartialPack()
        {
            ViewBag.allShapes = db.Shapes.ToList();
            return PartialView("PartialPack", db.Shapes.ToList());
        }
```

code console.log(data); return full partial view code, but when I see code of #viewer element its contain just this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add some code.

Comment: return in the controler? return PartialView("NameOfPartialView", model);

Comment: @tire0011 `return PartialView("NameOfPartialView", model);` equal `return PartialView(db.Shapes.ToList()); }` The problem is not this. In console (console.log(data)) data contain full partial view, but when its render on page ($('#viewer').html(data)) its not contain only this: 
`<html><head></head><body></body></html>` without other divs and canvas

Comment: @АзатИбатуллин Please don't post code in comments, post it in the question itself so we can read it.

Comment: @EJoshuaS okay, sorry, I fix it. Help please

Comment: what returns $('#viewer') does jquery find the control?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the content of the iframe with:

```
     $('viewer').contents().find('html').html('<html><head></head><body>test</body></hmtl>')
```

in your case:

```
   success: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
            $('#viewer').contents().find('html').html(data);
    },
```